# ExtJS: store, pagingToolbar and PHP session expire

Tags: php, session, extjs, paging, gridpanel

Let's imagine you are on a page with an ExtJS grid with a pagingToolbar. Let's imagine that you remain on this page for a while and that during this time your PHP session expires. When you hit "Next page" or "reload" on the grid, the call to the server will fail since it will answer with something informing you that you are not allowed to get the information (since your session has expired).

How can you handle that in the gridPanel in order to avoid it to get stuck? I hope this was clear enough..

Bye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some sort of heartbeat mechanism, which means that you must periodically send an AJAX call to your server to keep the PHP session alive. If you're using `Ext.direct` you can simply make use of the [`Ext.direct.PollingProvider`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.direct.PollingProvider) which is by far the most convenient way to implement such a heartbeat. If you're not using `Ext.direct` you can use [`Ext.TaskMgr`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.TaskMgr) or [`Ext.util.TaskRunner`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.util.TaskRunner) to call a function periodically in which you can simply issue an AJAX request.

The implementation details are left to the OP.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your answer.

This is one interesting way of solving the issue, I will have a look at it. But guess you want to notify the user that something went wrong because the data that the server sent is not the actual content to be displayed on the grid but an error message (maybe encoded in JSON: "Session expired. Logging out... + redirect"): is it possible to handle this problem that way?

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely possible. The "heartbeat" request is completely separated from the actual data request the store issues, so you can have a client-side event-handler that listens to this heartbeat event (I'm talking about the `Ext.direct`-approach) and reacts on the payload the event contains. We do this for exactly the same purpose: keep the session alive until a certain timespan has elapsed, then logout the user.